# Can not set focus on checkbox in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using react hook forms to create forms in my application:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, setFocus, handleSubmit } = useForm({
    defaultValues: { inputText: "", inputCheckbox: false }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="form">
        <br />
        <label>inputCheckbox</label>
        <input type="checkbox" {...register("inputCheckbox")} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <label>inputCheckbox2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" {...register("inputCheckbox")} />

        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setFocus("inputCheckbox");
          }}
        >
          setFocus inputCheckbox
        </button>

        <br />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I try to set focus when i click on the button, but it does not work, why and how to fix using the library API?

 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-feather-eh1crv?file=/src/App.js:0-899

Comment: I don't use `useForm`, but you have `inputCheckbox` named twice, you can't focus two elements at the same time, so not sure what `useForm` does, any errors in console.

Comment: You should add `type="button"` to your first button so it doesn't submit the form. With that change focus is moved to the first checkbox. Although I would update the style of the `:focus` state too, to make it visible.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros  Doing this fundamentally changes a submit's meaning, and effects user input, and I assume will make less sense for screen readers too, if you want to prevent a page submit because your making a SPA,  `e.preventDefault()` is usually the better option.

Comment: Not sure if I can understand what you mean. The first button should not submit a form but as it's inside a form and has no `type`, it defaults to `submit`.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros  Ah, yes.  didn't see the two buttons.  Indeed if the button is not meant to submit, `type="button"` is the way to go..